# What is replacement of QVariant in PySide6?

Tags: python, pyside

As [doc](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/considerations.html#qvariant) said, `QVariant` is removed in python. However, in some case, I still need `QVariant`.

```
class TreeNode(QObject):
    dataChanged = Signal(object, int) # here

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._itemData = {}
        self._childNodes = []

    def setData(self, value, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        self._itemData[role] = value
        self.dataChanged.emit(value, role)

    @Property(object, fset=setData, notify=dataChanged) # here
    def data(self, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        return self._itemData.get(role)
```

In code snippet above, I have to specify `QVariant` for `Signal` and `Property`. If I use object instead, it will shows

```
Invalid property assignment: unsupported type "PySide::PyObjectWrapper"
```

Comment: Try with `"QVariant"`

Comment: A property function cannot have arguments (it cannot be called), so that `role` is completely useless in the function definition.

Comment: The property and signal work perfectly fine in both PySide-6.6.1 and PySide-6.5.2. However, the API is broken, since there's no way to access data for any role other than the DisplayRole.