How to pass QQuickTextDocument pointer from QML to python?
I want to rewrite a Qt/C++ applicaiton in Python.
Which hash a QML_ELEMENT class that passes the QQuickTextDocument* from QML to CPP using Qt/Property. Qt/C++ works good.
Python version gives following error; abviously, Python version class doesn't recognize the poiner type? because QQuickTextDocument is not valid QML VALUE TYPE?
/main.qml:15:9: Unable to assign QQuickTextDocument to [unknown property type]
here is the c++ class declaration.
class Createable01 : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QML_ELEMENT
public:
    explicit Createable01(QObject *parent = nullptr);

signals:
    void textDocumentChanged();

public:
    Q_INVOKABLE void colorize(QQuickTextDocument *doc);

    QQuickTextDocument *m_textDocument;
    QQuickTextDocument *textDocument() const;
    void setTextDocument(QQuickTextDocument *newTextDocument);

private:
    Q_PROPERTY(QQuickTextDocument *doc READ textDocument WRITE setTextDocument NOTIFY
                   textDocumentChanged FINAL)
};

I tried writing the class in Python like this:
class Creatable(QObject):
    name_changed = Signal()
    textDocument: QQuickTextDocument

    def __init__(self, ):
        QObject.__init__(self)

    def get_textDocument(self):
        return self.textDocument

    def set_textDocument(self, newTextDocument):
        self.textDocument = newTextDocument

    doc = Property(QQuickTextDocument, get_textDocument, set_textDocument)

Using same QML file:
Window {
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    visible: true
    width: 640

    Creatable {
        id: highlighter

        doc: textArea.textDocument
    }
    TextArea {
        id: textArea

        height: 400
        width: 400

        anchors {
            centerIn: parent
        }
    }
}



I recommend typing it as QVariant which will simplify the interaction between QML/JS/Python. On the Python-side you can, on-demand, test to see if the QVariant contains a QObject* and/or QQuickTextDocument* since it may also contain null.

QVariant is removed from Pyside6; I tried typing.Any; not working. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77037480/what-is-replacement-of-qvariant-in-pyside6
